# Regarding tool for naming convention and comment

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I want to make a tool to check the naming convention and comments standard in C#. Can any one help me on that, what flow I have to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than write your own, why not customise [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis):

> StyleCop analyzes C# source code to
>   enforce a set of style and consistency
>   rules. It can be run from inside of
>   Visual Studio or integrated into an
>   MSBuild project.

Comment: +1. although it has to be said, that's it's not much fun to customise...or was that FxCop?

Comment: @Praveen: that's what stylecop does: StyleCop analyzes C# source code to enforce a set of style and consistency rules.

Comment: is any one help me out on this ?

Comment: @Praveen: `StyleCop` does what you want, so I'm not sure what other help you need?  Unless you are asking for someone to customize `StyleCop` for you?

Comment: PRAVEEN!- ardman gave you an answer and you are ignoring him >:(

Comment: thanks  ardman and  Neurofluxation i m looking forword.....

Comment: *thumbs up* (I'm only writing this bit in brackets to fill in the space to allow me to actually write this comment)...